# Chmod permission on future files

Tags: chmod

I want to make all the files in the directory `photo` readable, writable, and executable for all. Suppose I `chmod -R 777 photo` today. Then tomorrow there are new files coming into the directory `photo`. Will the change of permission affect those files as well?

Comment: Have you seen `man umask`.  However, what do you mean by `coming` into the directory?

Comment: @devnull So the server just downloads photos from the web every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not usually. You could have a cron job to chmod them. Or you could change the `umask` of processes writing to that dir to `000` to make it work as you wish.

If this is a desktop computer, you can bind a key combination through your desktop environment so once you copy files to the dir, you hit the combination and a chmod is executed.